# Calling one controller within another using spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I need to create two web applications using spring mvc. So from one application how can i redirect to another jsp which is at another application. Do i need to call controller of another application. If so, how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the redirect: prefix](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix) to achieve this. In the `request handler method` of the `Controller` of your first application add the `redirect:` prefix to the return string:

```
@Controller
class ControllerOfFirstApp{

@RequestMapping("/secondWebApp")
public String gotoSecondWebApp(){

String redirectURL="redirect:http://hostname/pathToSecondApp";
return redirectURL;
}
}
```

If the logical view name starts with "/", it will redirect relative to the current `Servlet context`, and a name such as `redirect:http://hostname/pathToSecondApp` will redirect to an absolute URL.